# How to run java10 inside Docker of python3.7?

Tags: java, python, docker, circleci

I have a circleci build that uses `python:3.6.6-stretch`. most of my services uses python, but I also need java10 + maven.

Now it seems impossible to install java10 inside python3 docker.

What is the best approach to have a docker that will support python and java ?

Comment: The title of your question is misleading, you should change it. Especially because someone might assume that you are asking for off-site content.

Comment: It's typically easier to start with a Java (or maven) container, then install Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 10 is not supported anymore and is removed from most of the PPAs. Do not use it if possible.

But if you still need specifically Java 10 you can take a look [how it is installed on top of an Ubuntu image by AdoptOpenJDK project](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/10/jdk/ubuntu/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full).

Your Dockerfile might look somewhat like this:

```
FROM python:3.6.6-stretch

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN set -eux; \
    curl -Lso /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk10-releases/releases/download/jdk-10.0.2%2B13/OpenJDK10_x64_Linux_jdk-10.0.2%2B13.tar.gz; \
    mkdir -p /opt/java/openjdk; \
    cd /opt/java/openjdk; \
    tar -xf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz; \
    jdir=$(dirname $(dirname $(find /opt/java/openjdk -name javac))); \
    mv ${jdir}/* /opt/java/openjdk; \
    rm -rf ${jdir} /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz;

ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk \
    PATH="/opt/java/openjdk/bin:$PATH"
```

Note: I dropped some SHA sum checks in favor of making the command shorter.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some research into public PPAs, and I couldn't find one that has a compilation of open-jdk10 for Debian-stretch. There is one for multiple versions of Ubuntu.
If you want maven + python 3 + java 10 installed I think you have a couple of options.

1. Find an image with maven + java 10 then install python 3 yourself.
2. Download and install the JDK by hand and setup the correct variables to add it to your PATH. See https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-java-10-on-debian-9/
3. Use an Ubuntu based image like this (https://github.com/FNNDSC/ubuntu-python3/blob/master/Dockerfile), so that you can use this PPA which has distributions of openjdk for 10.

Comment: add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java will fail you need to add apt-get install software-properties-common -y, and even than it will not work

Comment: @EhudLev Yeah you're right those are definitely manual steps. Need the -y to force auto-accept. What problem are you running into during the installation, though?

Comment: I am trying to install it inside the docker while it is running. I mean "docker run -it python:3.6.6-stretch bash" is it makes a different ?

Comment: @EhudLev Running a user inside the docker to install these packages (or test installing them) should be fine. Make sure you have sudo privilege as that user (if you're not root) so you can sudo before the apt-get installs. I'm going to pull down a copy real quick and see what kind of errors I get. Have to run for lunch soon but I can look at it again after I get back.

Comment: @EhudLev Woops it looks like that PPA removed the Java 10 download. Do you NEED Java 10 specifically? Can you use Java 11?

Comment: unfortunately need java 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195297/discussion-between-jazzepi-and-ehud-lev).